# ¿Agregar palabras claves imágenes ayuda a mejorar el SEO de una página web?

Tags: seo

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto, realizando una página web, la cual recibí una recomendación de cambiar los nombres de mis imágenes por nombres largos con palabras claves, ejemplo:

```
televisores_chile_sony_valpariso_<nombre-de-imagen>
```

Realizando esto:

- ¿Conseguiré aumentar mi *SEO* o solo conseguiré que Google me penalice por repetir muchas veces las palabras claves?

Son alrededor de 100 imágenes

Comment: Hola @Javier te recomendaría que mejores el título de tu pregunta para hacerla más específica. Tal como está puede atraer votos negativos o hasta cerrar la pregunta

Comment: El título sigue sin explicar el problema. Te recomiendo algo como: ¿Agregar palabras clave en el nombre de imágenes ayuda a mejorar el SEO de una página web?

Comment: Tu pregunta esta demasiado abierta, por favor se mas especifico en que  intentaste y cual es el problema que quieres resolver.

Answer (score 3):

Como todo excesivo uso de las herramientas que nos da google para posicionar nuestros sitios, puede ser penalizado si se usa abusivamente.

Según Google

> El uso de palabras clave para los atributos "alt" ("aglomeración de palabras clave") genera una experiencia negativa para el usuario y puede hacer que su sitio se considere spam. Concéntrese en crear contenidos útiles con mucha información y que utilicen las palabras clave de manera apropiada y en contexto. Le recomendamos que pruebe el contenido de su sitio con un navegador de solo texto como Lynx.

Fuente: [Google Webmaster](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/114016?hl=es)

Acá tengo un documento que realice hace poco sobre algunos tips de SEO que quizá te pueden ayudar: [Bases de posicionamiento](http://gbarrerasaez.cl/bases-del-posicionamiento-web-seo-organico/)

Muchos Saludos

Answer (score 2):

Mi experiencia me dice que indicar un nombre que describa la imagen como nombre de fichero siempre es una buena practica. No digo usar la palabra clave en todas las imágenes para conseguir posicionar una palabra. Lo que digo es que, usando el sentido común, un nombre de imagen que describa su contenido siempre es útil, ya sea una maquina o una persona quien lo lea.

Si la foto es un chico columpiándose, llamar a la imagen "chico-columpio.jpg" siempre va a ser positivo. Si alguien busca "chico columpio" en imágenes de google, la imagen saldrá en los resultados.

Poner en todas las imágenes la palabra clave que quieres posicionar, es una mala practica. Poner nombres que describan la imagen no.

Es preferible que llames a la imagen con el modelo exacto del producto, ya que una persona verdaderamente interesada en ese producto, acabará en tu web.

Un saludo.

Answer (score 1):

Puede ayuda pero si es excesivo lo que haces te va a penalizar.
El motor de seo tiene en cuenta el contexto y ese tipo de fraude es detectable desde hace muchos años.

Mejor aprende de SEO, hay muchos cursos en linea al respecto.

Answer (score 0):

Por mi experiencia te puedo contar que pongas a las imágenes y a los alt de las mismas lo que describa únicamente a esa imagen. Si es una televisión led 55 pulgadas llámala tv-led-55-p, y en el alt "televisión LED 55 pulgadas sony" por ejemplo. Nada de ponerle a todas las imágenes las keywords que quieras posicionar en tu página, y mucho menos solo las principales...

Google ya sabe que tu ciudad es Chile, no hace falta que se lo recalques en todos los lugares, de hecho no es una buena práctica sobrecargarlo por la fuerza, tal vez alguna keyword de la sección en la que están esas imágenes, pero ay te digo que sin sobrecargarlo. Céntrate en describir a la imagen